# Cloud service for Django app deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, google-cloud-platform

We are having webapp which is use Django and Mysql which run in Windows using Apache. Now we are planing to move into cloud service like

1) Google cloud

2) AWS

3) Azure

So to deploy existing Django and move MySQL into database into cloud  which one is easy tool from above 3 list. Or what is the approach that I can follow move my existing app into cloud

Answer (score 1):

The “easiest” approaches to deploying such app is probably using a [Platform as a Service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_as_a_service) (*PaaS*). Here are some of them to get you started, pick any, really:

- Python Anywhere (https://www.pythonanywhere.com/), focused on Python apps (hence Django as well)
- Heroku (https://heroku.com/)
- Clever-Cloud (https://www.clever-cloud.com/)
- Google App Engine (https://cloud.google.com/appengine)
- AWS ElasticBeanstalk (https://aws.amazon.com/fr/elasticbeanstalk/)
- Azure AppServices (https://azure.microsoft.com/services/app-service/)
- RedHat OpenShift (https://www.openshift.com/), open-source, available self-hosted or as a service

To me the first three are the easiest, but it all eventually boils down to personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

Asking which service is the "easiest" is very subjective and I'm biased towards AWS since that is the service that I got most of my certification from. In the end, you should play around with each and make your own decision.

With AWS, the best tool would be Elastic Beanstalk. Elastic Beanstalk is great for deploying easily while allowing customization.

Elastic Beanstalk with Django: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html

For your database, AWS allows migration from an external MYSQL database to their RDS service: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/sbs/CHAP_MySQL2Aurora.html#CHAP_MySQL2Aurora.mysqldump